# Can the Unity Facebook SDK be used with Mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure out if I can use this SDK for my Google distributed Unity Android App

- Can this SDK be used with Unity apps compiled for Android/iOS
  devices? It sounds like it may only work with Unity web based apps.
- If so, how would I configure this in the Facebook App Center?  As a: App on
  Facebook with Unity support, or Native Android/iOS app.
- Can I still distribute my game from Google Play and use Google In-App
  Purchase API's or do I need to update the app to use the Facebook App
  API exclusively?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes it can.

> The Facebook SDK for Unity complements Unity Technologies' seamless cross-platform support, providing a pure-Unity write-once, complete-everywhere experience across the key gaming platforms of Unity Web Player, Android and iOS.

2) Native Android/iOS app. See this for more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/ConfigureiOSAndroid/

3) Should be fine. I myself am using Google Play Game Services for my Android builds for achievements, alongside the Facebook SDK for its social features.

Comment: Could you please look into my question here? I am having trouble at the very first step itself.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388069/facebook-fb-init-fail-for-android-unity